# border in cascaded html tables

Tags: html, css, border

I have to display some data. I think it is better in my case to use tables instead of div because it allows to properly see the data even without **css**.

My solution that involves cascaded tables shows an ugly border offset that you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/u2rtfaa0/.

I tried to use this directive but it doesn't solve my problem.

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
```

I guess I did something wrong.

Comment: Are you intentionally making a cascaded table? Because problem goes when you convert it to one table.

Comment: Yes I do. Tables have different amount of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I come up with a solution, with live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/u2rtfaa0/9/

Basically I added `margin:-1px` to all table and elements, you css is now like this:

```
table { 
width: 100%;
}

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0; 
padding: 0;
margin:-1px;
}

.num {
width: 50px;
}
```

But I had to change width from 100% to a  certain value because extra white space ocurred on the right. However, if you want to make it still 100%, try adding -1 margins to various elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are reapplying a border on every "block", if you notice that sub-subtitle is 3px wide at the sides and bottom because it's enclosed by the title border, the subtitle border and its own border. This happen because you put subtitle in a new table, and sub-subtitle in a new table WITHIN the table within the table.

remove the extra tables. like so: http://jsfiddle.net/u2rtfaa0/2/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th class=num>min</th>
    <th class=num>nom</th>
    <th class=num>max</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td class=num>123</td>
    <td class=num>222</td>
    <td class=num>432</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Subtitle</th>
                <th class=num>888</th>
                <th class=num>777</th>
                <th class=num>666</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>foo</td>
                <td class=num>123</td>
                <td class=num>222</td>
                <td class=num>432</td>
            </tr>
</table>
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>SubSubtitle</th>
                        <th class=num>888</th>
                        <th class=num>777</th>
                        <th class=num>666</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>foo</td>
                        <td class=num>123</td>
                        <td class=num>222</td>
                        <td class=num>432</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There are the glitches on your jsfiddle ?

Comment: Damned ! I got your answer but in my case I need cascaded tables because all the tables don't have the same amount of columns and they are not aligned in the same way :(

Comment: Break out the tables and put them under one another instead. The margin/padding is set to 0 so they should end up straight under one another. However, you will still have the issue of the top and the bottom border of each table stacking on each other. However, you could think of that as a feature if you want; it makes a nice splitting border.

Comment: putting -1px on margin along with my fiddle will leave you the result you want, or what I assume you want. You can put a <td> tag with columns in each individual table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close each table as shown and add  margin:-1px  http://jsfiddle.net/u2rtfaa0/11/

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th class=num>min</th>
<th class=num>nom</th>
<th class=num>max</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td class=num>123</td>
<td class=num>222</td>
<td class=num>432</td>

</tr>
</table>
<tr>
<td colspan=4>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Subtitle</th>
<th class=num>888</th>
<th class=num>777</th>
<th class=num>666</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td class=num>123</td>
<td class=num>222</td>
<td class=num>432</td>
</tr>
</table>

<td colspan=4>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <th>SubSubtitle</th>
 <th class=num>888</th>
 <th class=num>777</th>
 <th class=num>666</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>foo</td>
 <td class=num>123</td>
 <td class=num>222</td>
 <td class=num>432</td>
 </tr>
 </table> 
 </td>                        

 </td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
table { 
width: 100%; 
}

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0; 
padding: 0; 
margin: -1px;
}

.num {
width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting it. It works but you are not consistent with your table tags. How does it work ?

Comment: it works because you are creating different table and merging the together you can add more content without affecting the width i guess